# Detecting IAP "Thank You" message

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS app with an IAP, I would like to detect when the user is tapping the OK button on the "Thank You" UIAlert that is shown at the end of each purchase.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any sure fire method.

Interested to know why. As this is an iOS alert it could be that the app is inactive while it's presented so you would receive an app delegate callback / notification when the alert is dismissed. I haven't tested that so you would need to confirm.

Comment: Yes there is no notification from storekit and no pointer to the alert view that you might set it a delegate.

Comment: While in the IAP cascade the app shows several alerts each alert puts the app on pause and each alert that is dismissed make it resume so my app's timer (game) is moving every time the app resuming. I only want it to start moving again after the user finished the IAP process completely.

Comment: You will need to add a flag that you set when a purchase is started and reset only when the app is made active and has received a success or failure callback. It can be easier to present a modal view to show progress while the purchase is in progress and keep that around until the user dismisses it.